# How to access a Google Form from the Google API?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-api, google-forms

The following code accesses Google Sheets in my account:

```
import gspread, json
import pandas as pd
from google.auth import default
from google.colab import auth

auth.authenticate_user()


creds, _ = default()
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

SCOPE = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]
SECRETS_FILE = "file.json"
SPREADSHEET = "File sheet"

# Based on docs here - http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html
# Load in the secret JSON key (must be a service account)
json_key = json.load(open(SECRETS_FILE))

# Authenticate using the signed key
#credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], SCOPE)

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
print("The following sheets are available")
for sheet in gc.openall():
    print("{} - {}".format(sheet.title, sheet.id))

# Open up the workbook based on the spreadsheet name
workbook = gc.open(SPREADSHEET)

# Get the first sheet
sheet = workbook.sheet1

# Extract all data into a dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())


column_names = {}

data.rename(columns=column_names, inplace=True)
# data.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp)
print(data.head())
```

I have a Google Form in this account as well. How can I access the Google Forms and return as a Pandas dataframe as I am doing it here?

Comment: In order to access Google Forms, it is required to use Google Form ID. In your situation, have you already known the Google Form ID, and do your access token has permission for accessing the Google Form? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest) And, can I ask you about your expected value? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `How can I access the Google Forms and return as a Pandas dataframe as I am doing it here?`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Isn't it a single Google API? I tried to access the Google Form ID but all I got is a standard Google API

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Isn't it a single Google API? I tried to access the Google Form ID but all I got is a standard Google API`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Please don't apologize but how can I access the Google Form ID?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you can open your Google Form, you can retrieve the Google Form ID as `###` of `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/###/edit`.

Comment: Yea but just using that alone is not enough. Its still giving me a list of available sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Yea but just using that alone is not enough. Its still giving me a list of available sheets.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Are you trying to access the responses directly using the Google Form API?